# Defiant vessel in TOS prequel

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-discovery, mirror-universe

I'm watching this series (ST), after a regular vision of TOS and TNG, in a nonlinear way. I have already watched also *Enterprise*, but I'm still at **S5** of **DS9**, and I've missed *Voyager* at all.

Now I'm watching *Discovery* (a little critic on this series may be the absurd Klingons' morphology, the exaggerated move away from original TOS' layout (okay, I understand its allocated budget was a grain as well as the effects possibilities, but in this way you have too much of a good thing! ), the incredible spore drive, but complexly I like this series very much, preserving in my opinion the spirit and style of ST with a great screenplay and direction).

After the emotional aside , the question:

Ref. *Chakoteya*, **S1 E10**, XVIII scene [**Ready room**]:

> **BURNHAM**: There may be some kind of temporal anomaly at play. It's unclear, but data suggests that in the future, the Defiant will encounter a phenomenon that'll bring it into this alternative universe's past.

I have thought and rethought about this assertion and my current memories about Defiant (as said, I'm fixed at **DS9** **S5** **E21**, *Soldiers of The Empire*, and in addition  I honestly **cannot figure out what does that have to do with the *Discovery*'s Defiant**), but I cannot hit the bull's-eye, solving my doubts.

I know the DS9 crew has traveled two times (basing on my current S5 E21 state of knowledge) into the *Mirror universe*, but I don't see when the Defiant fell into the timeline of Discovery.

So, what are they referring to with the future Defiant, and in which season and episode does this happens?

Comment: Might want to google how many ships in the US Navy have been named, for instance, "Ohio".

Comment: @ZeissIkon okay, I had thought the possibility of a homonymy case (so the mentioned Defiant has nothing to do with DS9), but still the hole about what they refer to with that future jump still remains. Is it something unknown basing on previous episodes?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The *U.S.S. Defiant* referred to in season 1 of *Star Trek: Discovery* is not the one seen in *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*.

It's the Constitution Class *U.S.S. Defiant* first seen in the original series episode *The Tholian Web*, where it's lost in some sort of weird space rupture. This is the future phenomenon that Burnham's line alludes to.

In the *Star Trek: Enterprise* episode *In a Mirror, Darkly*, it's revealed that this Defiant actually travelled into the Mirror Universe (and, simultaneously, back in time to the period covered by *Enterprise*), where it was eventually used by Empress Hoshi Sato to threaten mirror earth.

Memory Alpha has [the full story of this historic ship](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Defiant_(NCC-1764)).

Comment: Just a nitpick -- iirc, the web was put in place by the Tholians against the Enterprise; the area of space was in some way problematic ("breaking up", and later called "interphase", in the episode itself), which caused aberrant behavior on the part of the crew, and then caused the ship to "fade out" (apparently, going to the Mirror Universe....)

Comment: @Basya: ah right yes — I haven't actually seen either the Original Series or Enterprise episodes in question, I was just going from (and misunderstanding) Memory Alpha. Thank you! Hopefully corrected now.

Comment: @Basya I remember the *web* episode of TOS, but I don't remember well all these details. Moreover, I've watched *Enterprise* seasons, but I've missed several episodes. Honestly that of the mirror it wasn't clear to me (e.g., I didn't understand the invisible presence of the captain Archer in the mirror spaceship), for this reason I've in mind to rewatch the entire *Enterprise* without lacking parts.